# Запятая: "например тот, что/который/(...)"

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, местоимения

Выступает ли в таких случаях *например* как присоединителный союз, после которого не нужна запятая, а нужна только после самого примера, если есть продолжение? В данном случае она нужна только после "тот" или "та" (возможны другие падежи), или после самого слова "например" она также должна быть?

Пример: *Постоянно вспоминаются какие-то приятные моменты путешествия, например тот, когда нас позвали в этот "райский уголок", накормили ухой и чего-то налили.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае "**например**" *предшествует* именной группе, к которой относится (тот), поэтому обособляется только вместе с ней (после самого слова запятая не ставится):

http://ls-gramota.livejournal.com/3921.html

Comment: Спасибо! Я так и думал!)

Comment: Я бы не стал спрашивать — так бы и не сомневался, что не надо запятой, — если бы не увидел, что в Нацкорпусе бОльшая часть примеров с запятой. :(

Answer (score 0):

**Надо различать  сходные грамматические конструкции *например + тот* с разной пунктуацией.**

Вводное слово ***например*** может использоваться в качестве присоединительного союза для обособленного  оборота, тогда запятая после него не ставится. В том числе **например** может относиться к указательному слову с уточняющим значением в СПП:

Постоянно вспоминаются **какие-то приятные** моменты путешествия, **например тот**, когда нас позвали в этот "райский уголок", накормили ухой и чего-то налили.

Но запятая ставится в следующем предложении: Постоянно вспоминается, **например, тот**  момент путешествия, когда нас позвали в этот "райский уголок", накормили ухой и чего-то налили.

**Пример:**

Его выводило из себя, **например, то,** что барон сам сбегал на кухню, вместо того чтобы распорядиться подать завтрак.

Можно переделать:  Многое его выводило из себя, **например то,** что барон сам бегал на кухню, вместо того чтобы распорядиться подать завтрак.

Comment: Спасибо, я различаю! Правда, когда смотрел в Нацкорпусе, не обращал внимания, есть там обобщающее слово или нет, а значит, во многих случаях там правильно запятые стоят. Но одно точно нашёл, где лишняя.

Comment: Такие конструкции, как ваша (с обособлением указательного слова), редко встречаются, поэтому может показаться, что запятую надо ставить всегда. Ну и ошибочные написания тоже возможны. Собственно, я стала отвечать на вопрос, чтобы отметить следующее:  здесь не надо знать особых правил, кроме той информации, которая дается ещё в своде 1956 года.